# adding OnClick Listeners to buttons in a custom dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have a custom dialog class as follows where xmlView = R.layout.yourdialoglayout which has 2 buttons. How could I add listeners to these buttons?

heres my class:

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog {
public CustomDialog(Context context,int theme,int xmlView) {
    super(context,theme);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //Hide the title
    this.setContentView(xmlView);
    }

public void killDialog() {
    dismiss();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply attach an OnClickListener just as you would for an Activity, by using [View.SetOnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29):

```
public CustomDialog(Context context, int theme, int xmlView)
{
    super(context,theme);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // hide the title
    this.setContentView(xmlView);

    // your special button
    Button yourButton = findViewById(R.id.yourbutton);
    yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // your action
        }
    });
}
```

You can attach an action to your other button the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findViewById` to find the buttons, and set `OnClickListener` on them as usual

Comment: would I add it below the setContentView line?

Comment: Sorry for slow response. Yes, you must add it before `setContentView` otherwise it will return null